# How to force Polymer to re render table without any change in collection

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I want to rerender a table in polymer 2.0 bound to any array although no change has been done in that array.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[records.user.Stmt]]">
  <tr>
    <td>[[getDate(item)]]</td>
    <td>[[getAccountCurrency(item)]]</td>
    <td style="text-align:right">[[getValueBalance(item)]]</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

On screen, from a drop down list, I select the currency e.g. USD, then **getValueBalance(item)** should bring balance based on the selected currency that is already stored in the *records.user.Stmt* array

```
getValueBalance(item) {
    return item.Bal[this.selectedCurrency].amount;
}
```

If I change the order of records in the array, the table is refreshed correctly when currency is selected as shown below:

```
var tmp = this.records.user.Stmt.slice();
this.splice('records.user.Stmt',0,tmp.length);
for (var i = tmp.length-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
    this.push('records.user.Stmt',tmp[i]);
}
```

However, if i do not change the record order and push them in same order as was before splice, then table does not get refreshed.

Is there any way to force table to render content based on selected currency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3151), if you want to change how item is displayed based on the currency you should explicitly specify `currency` as a dependency in model binding function. Below is working example:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-repeat.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">

<dom-module id="poltest-app">
  <template>

    <paper-listbox selected="{{currency}}" attr-for-selected="value">
      <paper-item value="EUR">EUR</paper-item>
      <paper-item value="USD">USD</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>

    <table>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[records.user.Stmt]]">
        <tr>
          <td>[[getDate(item)]]</td>
          <td>[[getAccountCurrency(item, currency)]]</td>
          <td style="text-align:right">[[getValueBalance(item, currency)]]</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </table>
  </template>

  <script>
    /** @polymerElement */
    class PoltestApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'poltest-app'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          records: {
            type: Object
          },
          currency: {
            type: String,
            value: "USD"
          }
        };
      }

      connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        this.records = {
          user: {
            Stmt: [
              {
                date: new Date(),
                currency: 1,
                balance: {
                  EUR: 1.00,
                  USD: 2.00
                }
              },
              {
                date: new Date(),
                currency: 0,
                balance: {
                  EUR: 4.00,
                  USD: 5.00
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }

      getDate(item) {
        return new Date();
      }

      getAccountCurrency(item, currency) {
        return currency;
      }

      getValueBalance(item, currency) {
        return item.balance[currency];
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(PoltestApp.is, PoltestApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Another working example with **computed** properties and the `currency` explicit specified (though this is Polymer 1.x): http://jsfiddle.net/h25Lzeqy/